How to zoom out on a mobile phone
I have a web page with a table and div that have fixed sizes. width="1200px" for example.
The menu adapts well on mobile with the @media value css.
Cordialy
If I look at the page on a PC everything is fine but on a mobile device I can't zoom out.
I've tried looking at the viewport but without success.
I want the user to be able to zoom out of the page without changing the size of the header menu.
Cordialy

Hi, a side note: you are using a wrong tag [zoom-sdk], which is for Zoom SDK; instead, use [zooming]
